# How to schedule ec2 instance stop using chalice and lamda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chalice

I am scheduling ec2 instance shutdown everyday at 8 PM using chalice and lambda function.

I have configured the chalice but not able to trigger or integrate python script using chalice

import boto3
 #creating session to connect to aws

```
#defining instances to be started or stopped
myins = ['i-043ae2fbfc26d423f','i-0df3f5ead69c6428c','i-0bac8502574c0cf1d','i-02e866c4c922f1e27','i-0f8a5591a7704f98e','i-08319c36611d11fa1','i-047fc5fc780935635']
#starting ec2 instances if stopped
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
ec2client = boto3.client('ec2')
  for instance in ec2.instances.all():
      for i in myins:
       if i == instance.id and instance.state['Name'] == "running":
       ec2client.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[i])
```

I want to stop instance using chalice

Comment: Chalice will help you to deploy your function on AWS lambda but you need cloud watch event rules to trigger your lambda at 8 PM.

Comment: Thanks for the information  john , here i tried using zappa

Answer (score 0):

AWS Instance Scheduler does the job that you are looking for. We have used it for several months. It works as expected. You may check this reference: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/stop-start-instance-scheduler/